# How to Return Observable from inside Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this code that grabs a cached value:

```
getConfigurations(): Observable<SiteConfiguration[]> {
    return this.storageService.getSiteConfigurations().map(c => {
        if(c) {
            return c;
        }                         
        return this.httpClient.get<SiteConfiguration[]>(this.url + "/config").subscribe(c => c);
    });        
}
```

I cache the `SiteConfiguration` object, but need to go to the server to get it if it doesn't exist.  But I can't return the second observable inside the first, as it would be returning an `Observable<Observable<SiteConfiguration[]>>`.

I'm sure this is a common scenario but my google-fu failed to find an answer.

Comment: `.flatMap`, or one of its siblings (concat, switch, ...)?

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your code should look like this

```
getConfigurations(): Observable<SiteConfiguration[]> {
    return this.storageService.getSiteConfigurations().flatMap(c => {
        if(c) {
            return Obserbable.of(c);
        }                         
        return this.httpClient.get<SiteConfiguration[]>(this.url + "/config")
    })        
}



getCOnfiguration().subscribe(c => c);
```

Comment: great! thanks.  I had seen `flatMap` but didn't know the use of it.  After seeing your code it seems pretty obvious

Comment: just take your time to read about Observables and rxjs , is crazy the thinks you can do with that library